# DirectShow introduction material

Tags: directshow

I'm looking for some DirectShow introduction material. Can you please point me to some (web-enabled) presentations\ books\ sites etc.?

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- [Links to **DirectShow** and Multimedia Information](http://tmhare.mvps.org/links.htm#tech)
- [DirectShow in Windows SDK Docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd375454.aspx)
- Book: [Programming Microsoft® DirectShow® for Digital Video and Television](http://www.microsoft.com/learning/en/us/book.aspx?ID=6381&locale=en-us)

Comment: Good list! I have only ever found two books on DirectShow itself (the other being [Michael Linetsky's](http://www.amazon.com/Programming-Microsoft-DirectShow-Michael-Linetsky/dp/1556228554/ref=sr_1_3?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1337859637&sr=1-3), and not as good as Pesce's). I would start with Pesce. It has complete examples, though it's kind of shallow. MSDN has a complete transform filter example, but not a source filter example. One really needs to dig in lots of places to get the info one needs. [Here](http://flylib.com/books/en/3.375.1.62/1/) is a good, short intro, from a book on coding games.